# How to run war file without using eclipse

Tags: java

I have done a maven project in my eclipse and was generated a war file in my system.I want to run that war file in another system without using eclipse.Is it possible to run without downloading JDK and eclipse..

Comment: which web server is available on another system? you would be needing that atleast

Comment: I have downloaded the apache tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The ***.war*** file stands for 'Web Archive'. This is a packaged web application, which can be run by an Application server (Examples:  Glassfish / Tomcat / Weblogic, Wildfly)

The process of making an application server run the .war file is called ***Deployment***.

For example, a .war file can be deployed to Tomcat application server (I.E., made to run by tomcat) by simply copying the .war file to the **/webapps** folder of Tomcat.

**Here are the steps to deploy .war file on Tomcat:**

**Step 1:**  Build the ***.war*** file for the web application.

Suppose that the .war file is "**my-app.war**".

Verify that the **my-app.war** file contains the following:

```
  /WEB-INF/ folder and 
  /WEB-INF/web.xml file
```

---

**Step 2:** Verify the following settings in Tomcat config.
(This step can be skipped if Tomcat was installed with default settings)

```
autoDeploy :  true 
unpackWARs : true
```

(Note: These are default values. These will be set to true if Tomcat is installed with default settings.)

---

**Step 3:** Remove any conflicting entries or stale entries from Tomcat config.

For example, if the new app to be deployed is 'my-app', then make sure that the existing config of Tomcat does not have 'my-app' already registered for another application.

This can be checked by trying to browse http://localhost:8080/my-app.

If this link works, then it means that the name 'my-app' was already taken.

**Another way to find if the name already exists:**

If Tomcat is installed in **"C:\Tomcat8"**, 
then the registration for 'my-app' can be found at

**C:\Tomcat8\conf\Catalina\localhost\my-app.xml**

---

**Step 4:**  If steps 1, 2, 3 are cleared, then copy the my-app.war file to 'webapps' folder of Tomcat.

If Tomcat is installed in **"C:\Tomcat8"**, 
then the my-app.war file can be copied to

**C:\Tomcat8\webapps\my-app.war**

---

**Step 5:** Wait for Tomcat to automatically detect my-app.war file inside webapps and extract it to webapps/my-app folder.

Tomcat usually does this automatically. However, this process may sometimes not work either due to file permissions (Example: User does not have write permissions on webapps folder, or Tomcat is installed to C:\program files, which has read-only permissions) or due to folder being locked.

Try restarting the Tomcat service to fix the issue.

If restarting Tomcat does not fix the issue, then verify permissions of Tomcat service and re-install / execute Tomcat with the necessary permissions.

---

**More information:**

https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Top-5-ways-to-deploy-a-WAR-file-to-Tomcat

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

https://dzone.com/articles/how-deploy-war-file-using

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268260

Comment: I have downloaded the apache tomcat and already put the war file inside the webapps..But,could not be able to start the server when I run the startup inside bin folder

Comment: Hi Visakh, The web app may not be starting due to config issues. I updated the answer with settings to be verified n Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link to run WAR with tomcat -

[Deploy war in Tomcat](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war)

or a video - [Deploy the war in Tomcat Video](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-the-tomcat-server-usin)

Well, if this suffice your requirement, it is good else please mention the specific issue, if there is that you are facing.